# How no to redirect to the default view when browser gets refreshed in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my project the router is set up like this :

```
   myApp.component("rsapproot", {
        transclude: true,
        template: "<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>",
        $routeConfig: [
            { path: "/login", component: "rsapplogin", name: "Login" },
            { path: "/tenant", component: "rsapptenantid", name: "Tenant" },
            { path: "/my-dashboard", component: "rsappmyrdash", name: "MyDash" },
            { path: "/my-reports", component: "rsappmyreports", name: "AppReports"},
            { path: "/equipment-details/:type/:id", component: "rsequipmentdetails", name: "EquipmentDetails" },
            { path: "/my/resources", component: "rsappresourceslist", name: "AppResourceList" },
```

Now expected behaviour after F5 or when pasting URL is, respectively, having current path reloaded or navigating to the said path, instead the initial application path is loaded.

**For e.g. /my/resources gets redirected to /my-dashboard.**

**I know that in order to retain the page after reload app, a url representing the path should be given.**

But that thing is already there and the paths respectively are all unique.

Then what am I missing ?

Comment: you have keep your current url in localstorage to restore it after refresh

Comment: @JayantPatil Could you help me with an example ?